# Designing an mp3 equalizer in swt

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

Hi guys im building an mp3 application which has a equalizer.what i wanted to know is are there any eclipse project of equalizer and audio widgets in swt.?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in audio but maybe the [Nebula Oscilloscope Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/oscilloscope/oscilloscope.php) is worth a try. I don't know if it completely fits your needs.

Examples:

[image]

You can find example snippets of the Oscilloscope Widget here: [git.eclipse.org](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/tree/widgets/oscilloscope/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.oscilloscope.snippets/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/oscilloscope/snippets). The API for the widget can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/oscilloscope/doc_20100825/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no existing widget for Equalizer in SWT. It should be easy to do this with a bunch of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Slider` widgets.

How to use Slider:Ex:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTSliders.htm